# Merging two divergent repositories on different remotes

Tags: git, github, merge, repository, gitlab

Me and my colleague set up a new repository on both GitHub and GitLab. All was nice, but due to a misunderstanding, he was pushing to GitHub and I was pushing to GitLab. We set up rep mirroring on GitLab but only one-way, which caused our repositories to diverge. Now, I'd like to merge them, and migrate to only GitLab, but when I did:

```
git remote add gitlab https://username@gitlab.com/username/rep.git
git push --mirror gitlab
```

I got the following error:

```
remote: GitLab: You are not allowed to force push code to a protected branch on this project
! [remote rejected] branch only on GitLab (pre-receive hook decline)
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
! [remote rejected] origin/HEAD -> origin/HEAD (deny updating a hidden ref)
! [remote rejected] origin/master -> origin/master (deny updating a hidden ref)
error: failed to push some refs to URL OF THE REP ON GITLAB
```

While I could just try to copy and paste the code to the repository on GitLab, I'd like to do it a clean way (if such a way even exists).

Answer (score 1):

Take a closer look at gitlab's error message:  "You are not allowed to force push code **to a protected branch** on this project".  By default, gitlab designates the `master` branch as "protected", and admins for the project may optionally designate other protected branches as well.  So you need to find a way to avoid having to force-push `master`.

This is not a situation I've personally encountered before, but the first thing I would try would be (after backing up my local repo, just in case!) to create a new branch off your local master, pull from gitlab and merge its master into yours, push back to gitlab (which should no longer require master to be a force-push), and then merge the new branch you created (your old master) into the gitlab master.

Alternately, if your local repo is in exactly the state you want to be "current" in gitlab, there's also the option of deleting (or renaming) the project in gitlab, then creating a new one to replace it, based on your local copy.  This would avoid having to (re-?)merge the two versions of the project and (unlike copy/pasting the content) would preserve all of the history, as your local repo knows it.